# Rocket Universe hung deleting multipart file

Tags: universe, u2

I'm having a process hang on trying to delete a part of a multipart file.  There's a lock on the file, but the process trying to do the delete is the one that holds the lock.  What could be causing it to hang?

Our product uses a multipart file called MR.WORK.  A new part gets created for each process, with a part name consisting of the letter U and the userno, so here it's MR.WORK,U-3.  Let's say I'm logged in as foo, and the product is also logged in as foo, running in a phantom.

```
>PORT.STATUS USER foo

There are currently 2 uniVerse sessions; 1 interactive, 1 phantom

  Pid....  User name.  Who.  Port name.....  Last command processed............
    23144  foo            2  /dev/pts/2      PORT.STATUS USER foo
  Pid....  User name.  Who.  Last command processed............................
     2086  foo           -3  DELETE-FILE DATA MR.WORK,U-3
```

It get there and just hangs forever.  Something else has an IN type group lock on the same inode, but I gather that IN is just informational and not really locking.

```
>LIST.READU EVERY 

Active Group Locks:                                     Record Group Group Group
Device.... Inode....  Netnode Userno   Lmode G-Address.  Locks ...RD ...SH ...EX
      2068  21630372        0      2    9 IN        400      1     0     0     0 
      2068  21502283        0     -1   57 RD        400      0     1     0     0 

Active Record Locks:
Device.... Inode....  Netnode Userno   Lmode        Pid Login Id Item-ID.............
      2068  21630372        0     -3    9 RU       2086 foo      MR.WORK,U-3
```

I'm stumped. MR.WORK,U-3 part is not particularly large.   I've tried deleting and recreating the file and we'll see if that helps, but I'm not hopeful.   Ideas?

Comment: Are you using some sort of external tool or performing this action from a PHANTOM process? I did a quick test with as a non-privileged user and can't replicate what is happening to you.  I can delete my part file with no issues. Could you elaborate on how you are executing this command?

Comment: It is in a phantom.  I went ahead and opened a case with Rocket support, I'll update here for the curious when I hear back.

Comment: Rocket support was also stumped.  We're just going to work around and avoid the issue.